# NodeJS specify node_modules path for require

Tags: node.js, gulp, require

I have a project containing 2 entry points and so 2 package.json. I'm using gulp in this 2 folders to build javascript/less files.

I would like to use common functions to avoid code duplication.
here is the structure

- dirA/

  - node_modules/
  - gulpfile.js
- dirB/

  - node_modules/
  - gulpfile.js
- gulp

  - bootstrap.js

in the gulp/bootstrap, i have somthing like that

```
    'use strict';

global._ = require('lodash');
global.gulp = require('gulp');
global.$ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
global.argv = require('yargs').argv;
global.source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
global.buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
global.watchify = require('watchify');


/**
 * Handle tasks errors
 * @param {Object} err
 */
global.onError = function onError(err) {
  if (isProd()) {
    $.util.log($.util.colors.red(err));
    process.exit(1);
  } else {
    $.util.log($.util.colors.red(err));
    this.emit('end');
  }
};

/**
 * return true if argv env is prod
 * @return {boolean}
 */
global.isProd = function isProd() {
  return argv.env === 'prod';
};

global.isWatch = function() {
  return !!argv.watch;
};

$.util.log($.util.colors.yellow('Production env: ', isProd()));
$.util.log($.util.colors.yellow('Watch mode: ', isWatch()));
```

In the dirA/gulpfile and dirB/gulpfile, i would like to import gulp/bootstrap, with `require('../gulp/bootstrap');`top of the gulpfile.js.
But doing this, require function cannot find modules required in bootstrap.js, even if i require the bootstrap file in a folder containing the node_modules/ folder. It search for node_modules/ in the gulp/ folder...

Is it a way to tell require to use a base path ? like `[process.cwd(), 'node_modules'].join('/');`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following in `bootstrap.js`:

```
function requireFromCwd(moduleName) {
    return require([process.cwd(), 'node_modules', moduleName].join('/'));
}

global._ = requireFromCwd('lodash');
global.gulp = requireFromCwd('gulp');
global.$ = requireFromCwd('gulp-load-plugins')();
global.argv = requireFromCwd('yargs').argv;
global.source = requireFromCwd('vinyl-source-stream');
global.buffer = requireFromCwd('vinyl-buffer');
global.watchify = requireFromCwd('watchify');
```